# SQL Query to list records for last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need query to list all the records for the date, incase if records are not present then query should list 0

```
SELECT  Count(C.ConversionStatusID) Visits, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ActionDate,110) ActionDate
FROM Conversion C
WHERE C.ConversionStatusID = 2 AND 
      ActionDate Between DateAdd(day,-7,GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ActionDate,110) 
Order BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ActionDate,110) DESC
```

Expected output should always result 7 records, Sample result should be as below

```
  ActionDate    Visits
  01-09-2015    1
  01-08-2015    5
  01-07-2015    0
  01-06-2015    0
  01-05-2015    3
  01-04-2015    8
  01-03-2015    0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: You need to create a query returning the last 7 days and `LEFT JOIN` it to your stuff.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, exactly that is what I thought, but I am unable write the query, Should I loop?

Comment: You can use [`recursive CTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @PM77-1 what do you mean by use a recursive CTE? I can't begin to think of why you would need that here.

Comment: @nikhilreddy you don't need a loop here. You need a numbers or tally table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: I know I answered this question before but can I find it....

Comment: @SeanLange - you can use a recursive CTE if you don't have a sequence table to make a table for the last 7 days.  First select the day 7 days ago then recurse selecting the next day which is less than the current day.

Comment: @SeanLange - I suggested CTE to dynamically `UNION` 7 dates together.

Comment: @Hogan you could use a rCTE for counting much like you can use a rock to drive a screw into wood. It will work but it is completely the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @SeanLange Wow, where did that attitude come from?  I'll go now, you can stay and be nasty to yourself.

Comment: I apologize that my comment was rude. However, using a cte for counting is pretty much the same thing as a loop. For a small set like this it wouldn't matter but somebody will find that code and replicate it to a large set and the performance will be truly horrible. Using a table valued constructor will result in much better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have date table for the last 7 days, you can then do `left join`

```
with cte (value, n)
as
(
  select DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day,0,getdate()),0) as value,1 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, value) as value, n+1
  from cte
  where n < 7
)
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cte.value,110) as ActionDate ,  Count(C.ConversionStatusID) Visits
from cte
left join Conversion C
ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.ActionDate,110) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cte.value,110)
and  C.ConversionStatusID = 2
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cte.value,110) 
Order BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cte.value,110) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, but you're going to have to play around with what should be a date and what should be a datetime.  It's not at all clear where or when you want a time component.  In particular, your `WHERE` clause seems to contradict the rest of your query since it doesn't strip the time.  For example, if `GETDATE()` is January 12 at 2 PM, is January 11 at 1 PM one day ago or two?   What about January 5 at 1 PM, then, because the `WHERE` clause is stripping that off.

If a date is 00:00 to 23:59 (although the `WHERE` clause is still off):

```
;WITH Dates ([Date]) AS (
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-2,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-3,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-5,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE) UNION
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()) AS DATE))
SELECT  D.Date,
    COALESCE(Count(C.ConversionStatusID),0) Visits
FROM Dates D
LEFT JOIN Conversion C
    ON D.[Date] = CAST(C.ActionDate AS Date)
WHERE C.ConversionStatusID = 2 AND 
      ActionDate Between DateAdd(day,-7,GetDate()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ActionDate,110) 
Order BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ActionDate,110) DESC
```

You could get away with not using a CTE if you had a Numbers or tally table, but for something this small it really won't matter that much.